# Give data from MySQL to golang template

Tags: go, go-templates

i give a dataset from mysql-database to go-template. the result have multiple rows but all values is one string!?

```
type Tasks struct {
    tid          int
    pid          int
    uid          int
    del          int
    finisch      int
    open         int
    inprocess    int
    abnahme      int
    fertig       int
    finischdatum string
    erstellt     string
    start        string
    ende         string

    name         string
    beschreibung string
}

type Daten struct {
    Tabledata        []*Tasks
}

d := Daten{}
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE pid=? AND del=0", pid)
        checkError(err)

        defer rows.Close()

        rs := make([]*Tasks, 0)
        for rows.Next() {
            rst := new(Tasks)
            err := rows.Scan(&rst.tid, &rst.pid, &rst.uid, &rst.del, &rst.finisch, &rst.open, &rst.inprocess, &rst.abnahme, &rst.fertig, &rst.finischdatum, &rst.erstellt, &rst.start, &rst.ende, &rst.name, &rst.beschreibung)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }

            rs = append(rs, rst)
        }

        d.Tabledata = rs
```

template:

```
 {{ range $key, $values := .Tabledata }}
                    <li><strong>{{ $key }}</strong>: </li>

                    {{range $values}}


                        {{.}}



                    {{end}}


                 {{ end }}
```

When I look in the first range and give me the $values as one string and the second range is death.

What's my Problem?

Comment: .Tabledata is a slice of *Tasks so $key is an index and $values the value at $key. But, $values is of type *Tasks, so it is not a slice or an array, so you can't loop on it.

Comment: How do I do that? Do you have an example? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, since you didn't tell, I guess the variable 'd' is passed to the template. 'd' is of type Daten and thus contain a field named TableData. This field is a slice of *Tasks. This is why in your template you **can** loop on it using range.

The range keyword returns two values, the first one, '$key' in your code, is the index of the slice, and the second one, '$values' in your code is the value pointed by TableData[$key]. Because TableData is a slice of type *Tasks, that means $values is of type *Tasks. So not an array nor a slice.

That means, you **can't** loop on $values because it's not a slice. But, you can access all the exported fields of Tasks. So depending on what you want to display in your template, you can do the following:

```
// Inside the firts range
<li><strong>{{ $key }}</strong>: </li>
name: $values.Name
open: $values.Open
```

Note the uppercase on the field's name, in order to access a field it shall be exported, and thus starts with an upper case in the type declaration.